# Library code to compare arbitrary array types?

Tags: java, arrays

`Arrays.equals()` is overloaded for all primitive arrays and `Object[]`, but given arrays of arbitrary component type, is there a routine in any well-known library that can compare them?

I.e. this will probably be a method like `equals(Object, Object)` which can accept `Object[]` as well as `int[]`, `byte[]`, etc.

Comment: `int[]` is not a subclass of `Object[]`, that's where all the trouble starts.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yeah, exactly. Arrays seems to be a design fail in the type system....

Comment: Don't judge them so fast: before autoboxing/unboxing there was really no way a piece of code could polymorphically operate on primitive and referenc arrays.

Comment: Also, conflating different primitive types would have performance issues, and the main purpose of arrays is performance.

Comment: I don't understand the question. `Arrays.equals()` can compare arrays of any type, because a `AnyComponentType[]` is a `Object[]`.

Comment: @JBNizet Have a look at Marko Topolnik's first comment. `int[]` is not a sub-type of `Object[]` and you cannot use `Arrays.equals(Object[], Object[])` on `int[]` for example. Otherwise, `Arrays.equals()` does not need so many overloaded versions.

Comment: Have you looked at the Apache Commons libraries? They provide a large number of missing functions.

Comment: Ah, OK. I thought you were looking for a way to compare, for example two arrays of Strings, and were confused because all he found was equals(Object[], Object[]). I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Bob 's tip, I found the following method in Commons Lang that does what I want:

[`public static boolean isEquals(Object array1, Object array2)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#isEquals%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29).